# Embedded Youtube video's thumbnail is blurry

Tags: jquery, html, css, youtube, embed

I'm embedding the lastest video from a youtube channel on my website. However, when it is displayed, the thumbnail for the video is very blurry/sd. Is there anyway I could force a hq thumbnail? 
A live demo is available [here](http://mkurapov.tk).
Also, when I press return on my browser after the latest button is clicked, the thumbnail's quality becomes what it should be.
Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#watch').on('click', function () {
    $(".iframe-container").show(300, function() 
    {
        $(".iframe-container iframe").css('opacity', 1);
        $(".info").css('opacity', 0);
        $("#watch").css('opacity', 0);
        $(".info").css('z-index', 1);
        $("#watch").css('z-index', 1);
        $("video#bg-vid").css('opacity', 0);   
    });
    $("#return").show("fast", function() {  $("#return").css('opacity', 1);});
});


  $('#return').on('click', function () 
  {
    $(".iframe-container").fadeOut("fast",function() 
    {
        $(".iframe-container iframe").attr('style', '');
        $(".info").attr('style', '');
        $("#watch").attr('style', '');
        $("#return").attr('style', '');
        $("video#bg-vid").attr('style', '');
        $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));  //stops video
    }); 
  });
});
```

And the css for the iframe:

```
.iframe-container
{
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    top:160px;
    width:55%;
    height: 55%;
    color:white;
    font-size: 40px;
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    margin:auto;

}
.iframe-container iframe
{
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:    opacity 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition:      opacity 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:     opacity 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try adding `&vq=hd1080` to the end of your iframe. So `http://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=NUTV&vq=hd1080`

Comment: It's still the same, but thanks though!

Comment: So I looked into this a little bit. The hqdefault screenshot itself is blurry, which causes the video to be blurry. here is the hqdefault: http://img.youtube.com/vi/qCXdEendTgw/hqdefault.jpg

Notice if you make it the appropriate size it looks like crap. My guess, youtube chose a screenshot that was in mid move for the camera. Try selecting a different thumbnail in the youtube video manager. Hope this helps!

Comment: The screenshots themselves are decent quality, the problem was that the iframe wasn't loading fully. I added   $('iframe').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));  right after the button clicked so that it forces to refresh the iframe and load a better thumbnail. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issues occurs mostly on Firefox and what helped me was having ?autoplay=1 after the video id. src="www.youtube.com/embed/{video_id}?autoplay=1"
Hope it helps